# Javascript: How to enhance mouse scroll to targeted section

Tags: javascript, scroll, action

I have a question, please help

- how we can read scroll event (mouse scroll to top or down) using Javascript?
- and how to trigger some event after we read the mouse scrolled

The structure will go like this

```
<div id="listofstuff">
<div class="anitem">
   <span class="itemname">Item1</span>
   <span class="itemdescruption">AboutItem1</span>
</div>
<div class="anitem">
   <span class="itemname">Item2</span>
   <span class="itemdescruption">AboutItem2</span>
</div>
<div class="anitem">
   <span class="itemname">Item3</span>
   <span class="itemdescruption">AboutItem3</span>
</div>
<div class="anitem">
   <span class="itemname">Item4</span>
   <span class="itemdescruption">AboutItem5</span>
</div>
<div class="anitem">
   <span class="itemname">Item5</span>
   <span class="itemdescruption">AboutItem5</span>
</div>
```

Let's say, first time user come to my web, they will see item 1
after the scroll down, the page is automatically smooth scroll to item 2

NOW WHEN THEY ARE IN ITEM 2

- if they are scroll down - it goes to item 3
- if they are scroll up - it goes back to item 1

This website doing what I want to achieve: http://onlinedepartment.nl/

+1 for the best answer : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JavaScript to listen for the "mousewheel" event.

And then use the events e.wheelDelta to figure out what direction the user has scrolled.

I had to use [a debounce function I found here](http://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls/) to prevent the event being fired to many times causing the slides to scroll to the bottom.

```
var amountOfSlides = 4;
var counter = 1; //at slide
var main = document.getElementById('main');
var currentPos = 0;

//The scroll event fires way to many times so we need to use
//debounce to only get the event once per scroll;
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', debounce(function(e) {

    //Check to see if the scroll is going up or down.
    if(e.wheelDelta >= 0) {

        //going up so make sure that the user isn't already at the top
        if(counter <= 1) return;
        currentPos = currentPos + window.innerHeight;
        counter--;

    } else {

        //going down. make sure the user is not at the bottom.
        if(counter >= amountOfSlides) return;
        currentPos = currentPos - window.innerHeight;
        counter++;
    }

    //change the position of the margin so that the slides move.
    document.getElementById('main').style.marginTop = currentPos + "px";

}, 250));

// http://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls/
function debounce(fn, delay) {
    var timer = null;
    return function () {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            fn.apply(context, args);
        }, delay);
    };
}
```

For the transition between slides I used CSS3 Transitions because they are smoother than JavaScript animations.

The only problem with this is when a user resizes the window (a refresh would be needed) but I hope this gives you a good start, because this issue could easily be sorted, as the slides resize to be 100% of the height of the window using CSS.

```
html, body, #main{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
#main {
    transition:1s;
}
article {
    height:100%;
}
```

I didn't use your HTML for simplicity but you can easily change it yourself.

```
<section id="main">
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
    <article></article>
</section>
```

Here is a jsFiddle to show you how it works, hope this helps. http://jsfiddle.net/9wrDT/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use this nice jquery plugin https://github.com/brandonaaron to avoid too much struggle with native mouse events for all browsers...
Then you can just scroll until the right place on mouse events:
    $(function() {

```
   $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

       this.animate({  
          scrollTop:theoffset  
       }, 'slow');  

       event.preventDefault();

   });

});
```

stolen from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/